# custom array adapter , can't access variables

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

im new on android

i try create my custom arrayadapter.

I want to access the layout variables from tmpview, but I can't do that. The man in the video I watched was doing the same and he could reach

how can i reach this variables ?

I also added "kotlin-android-extensions" to the plugins section

```
package com.example.burclar

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import java.security.AccessControlContext
import java.util.zip.Inflater

class myArrayAdapter(var gelencontext: Context, resource: Int,var burcAdlar: ArrayList<String>, var burcTarihler: ArrayList<String>, var burcResimler: ArrayList<Int>): ArrayAdapter<String>(gelencontext, resource){

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var tmpview = convertView

        if(tmpview == null){
            tmpview = LayoutInflater.from(gelencontext).inflate(R.layout.my_list_view_element,null)
        }

        tmpview.burcMiniYazi = burcAdlar[position] //there is a problem "unresolved reference"
        tmpview.burcMiniResim = burcResimler[position] //there is a problem "unresolved reference"
        tmpview.burcMiniTarih = burcTarihler[position] //there is a problem "unresolved reference"

        return tmpview!!
    }

}
```

my_list_view_element.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/burcMiniYazi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/burcMiniResim"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/burcMiniResim" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/burcMiniResim"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/burcMiniTarih"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/burcMiniResim"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/burcMiniResim" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/burcMiniResim" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlZpL.png)

Comment: Use [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) . Kotlin synthetic is deprecated .

Comment: If you're using synthetics, you have to import them as extension properties. If you hover the red text, the IDE should give you the option to do it for you.